# Are glueballs confined without a connection to quarks?

Tags: standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, confinement, gluons

Without being bound to quarks through the strong force, is there any reason why glue balls would be confined? Are they confined

Comment: The strong coupling constant increases with distance

Comment: @LSS but does that remain true without the quarks?

Comment: Quarks impede infrared slavery, as you observe on the β function… and gluons are color charged.

Comment: This question and answers are relevant to your question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/328159/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, gluons are confined, as they couple to themselves, and experience the strong force they underlie/enable/mediate even more *strongly* than quarks do.

Quarks, if anything, appear to *weaken* the strong force when they appear as loops in the relevant Feynman graphs (screening: technical gobbledygook... don't worry about it).

In "[quenched QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quenched_approximation)", a toy theory of the strong interactions which only has quarks as targets/recipients of the strong force, the strong force is even stronger / more confining than that of our real quarkful world. In it, gluons bind themselves into hadrons called [glueballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball).

In our real word, such glueballs mix/get-absorbed/obscured with conventional hadrons and are subtler to study.